# Launch click once application across all browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, clickonce

Is it possible to launch click once application from all browsers and not just from IE? If the application is launched from other browsers, it gets downloaded instead of launching.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but only via 3rd Party applications, such as [ClickOnceforChrome](http://www.clickoncechrome.com/) or [FFClickOnce](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ffclickonce/) (both untested).

Is it such a problem it downloading and not auto-running?

Unfortunately, you can't force browsers to natively support all ways of opening all files...